# JAVA: How use Gazettes with Stanford NLP?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I read this [faq](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#gazette) but i not understand. I try with this code:

```
   Properties pp=new Properties();  
   pp.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
   pp.put("ner.useSUTime","false");

   pp.put("useGazettes","true");
   pp.put("gazette","C:\\gaz.txt");

   StanfordCoreNLP s=new StanfordCoreNLP(pp);
```

This is String: "Dan became a member of the Music friends association in 2008"

the gazette file is:

```
  CLASS Music friends association
```

But "Music friends association" is not recognized by NER.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect your system to recognize it? DO you have it inside gaz.txt ?

Comment: Should recognize named entities in the file gaz.txt there is only this line "CLASS Music friends association"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given there:

> If a gazette is used, this does not guarantee that words in the gazette are always used as a member of the intended class, and it does not guarantee that words outside the gazette will not be chosen. It simply provides another feature for the CRF to train against. If the CRF has higher weights for other features, the gazette features may be overwhelmed.

So there is not guarantee that your phrase will be tagged in any way.  The alternative is

> either the regexner or the tokensregex tools included in Stanford CoreNLP

Comment: How does one use a gazette with tokensregex? Also if my entity spans multiple tokens like "New York", how do I do a lookup in the location gazette using tokensregex as it takes in and looks at only one token at a time?

Comment: Well tokensregex is an if and only if match, whereas gazette is a suggestion.  What are you going for: a strict match, but for a particular subset of words?  Like New York should be accepted but Los Angeles should not be accepted as a location in some circumstances?  Maybe the Stanford team will see this and chime in, but I think you might want to favor tokensregex.